# Как передать focus() внутрь iframe, чтобы ловить события keydown?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, iframe, вконтакте

`iframe` приложение для ВКонтакте на D3js рисует всякие штуки, и для интерактива слушает клавиатуру - события `keydown` на элементе `<body>`.

Как при загрузке приложения перенести фокус в мой iframe, чтобы нажатия на клавиши сразу стали попадать в мой скрипт?

После окончания загрузки страницы ВК с приложением, нажатие на пробел, например, прокручивает страницу вниз, а JS это событие не получает. Приходится предлагать юзеру кликнуть мышкой в `iframe`, чтобы начали работать клавишные команды.

DOM-элементу `<svg>` дать фокус не выходит: "`TypeError: svgnode.focus is not a function`". Добавление атрибута `focusable=true` ничего не изменило. `document.activeElement` имеет значение `<body>` этого iframe'а, но пробел прокручивает всю страницу, вместо действий в моем js-аппе.

**Upd.** если создать текстовое поле, то ему дать focus() удается. И тогда мой скрипт начинает ловить нажатия на клавиши (которые при этом появляются в поле). Т.е. желаемое возможно. Осталось нащупать, как. Не держать же поле формы только для ловли фокуса.

---

**Upd. 7 Октября.** Всё ещё (опять) актуален вопрос. Всё то же: ВКонтакте iFrame приложение, FireFox (Mac). Нужно как-то сразу начать ловить нажатия на клавиши из iFrame – без дополнительных действий со стороны пользователя. В частности, на стрелочки.

К последнему комментарию [[@Eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto): после раскомментирования того кода в FF не заработало.

Comment: не понятно, window.focus не работает ?http://run.plnkr.co/h4ZkcODg0C0yFFNp/ http://plnkr.co/edit/QckxkrE99cqaXlngdTvm?p=preview

Comment: или даже так... http://plnkr.co/edit/QckxkrE99cqaXlngdTvm?p=preview

Comment: @eicto, на Mac Firefox не работает, пока не кликнуть внутри iframe. В Chrome работает.

Comment: а первый пример ?

Comment: Я все примеры проверял. Сейчас "[Not found](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f7wh7ox6873bvr7/Screenshot%202014-05-12%2009.10.26.png)" первый пример.

Comment: чет он пропадает, http://plnkr.co/edit/IdcyowenMm2x1HUuJCuL?p=preview  если что просто раскомментируйте все в том что работает в хроме